# 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices

I am trying to learn how to implement microservices with spring boot application and trying to run the spring boot application on the server port 9091.But always showing the below error :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-28 12:37:50.615 ERROR 3828 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

I also try to kill the port number using command prompt window , still that error is coming up again and again.